# pgfplots 3D plots size versus 2D plots size

Tags: pgfplots, plot, 3d

I wanted to create a 3D plot but it's not possible for me to set the right size. Should I try out until I find the right values for height and width for the 3D plot or is there an easy way to find them?

Thanks in advance

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                height=5cm,
                width=5cm,
                axis lines=center,
                xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
                xmin=-13,xmax=13,ymin=-13,ymax=13,
                xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
                    ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                view={30}{25},
                height=5cm,
                width=5cm,
                axis lines=center,
                xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty, ztick=\empty,
                xmin=-13,xmax=13,ymin=-13,ymax=13,zmin=-13,zmax=13,
                xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, zlabel=$z$,
                    ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: hm. The 3d axis is scaled such that it fits into the prescribed `width,height` -- provided you use `axis lines=box`. In this case, it also scales in the same way, but since `axis lines=center` uses less space, it wastes lots of it. Sounds like a defect.

Comment: That said, you may want to take a look at `\usepackage{tikzscale}` which might fit your needs